# ProcessException: Operation not permitted

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to run a file with arguments from dart code (This file is in the app's container) on MacOS. How can I do it in a sandbox? I don't want to disable sandbox because then i can't publish app in App Store.

I tried this code `ProcessResult result = await Process.run(path, [-pa], includeParentEnvironment: true);`

but I'm getting error: `ProcessException: Operation not permitted`.